# Disconnected after 10 when debugin remote kube java application

Tags: java, kubernetes, debugging, remote-debugging

in my deployment file I add

```
      - name: JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS
        value: '-Xdebug -agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,address=0.0.0.0:5005,server=y,suspend=n'
```

and debug port:

```
      - name: debug-port
        containerPort: 5005
        protocol: TCP
```

I need to debug my application from the start so when I deploy application run port forwarding and run debug application in sts everything works. Problem is that it disconnected after 10s so I can debug nothing. Any advise how to fix this ?